# Keystore Alias Null Error

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, jks

I am trying to configure a product called Hermes for a digital signature.

I have a file MyCert.pfx which I specified in its configuration as follows:

```
<component id="keystore-manager-for-signature" name="Key Store Manager for Digital Signature">
    <class>hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.security.KeyStoreManager</class>
    <parameter name="keystore-location" value="/opt/mycompany/certs/MyCert.pfx"/>
    <parameter name="keystore-password" value="12345678"/>
    <!-- parameter name="key-alias" value="joeblank"/-->
    <!-- parameter name="key-password" value="12345678"/-->
    <parameter name="keystore-type" value="PKCS12"/>
    <parameter name="keystore-provider" value="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"/>
</component>
```

Hermes throws an exception like this:

```
hk.hku.cecid.ebms.spa.task.MessageValidationException: Cannot sign the ebxml message
    by hk.hku.cecid.ebms.pkg.SignatureException: [10204] Cannot sign message Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Message: null
    Try to retreive key alias[null] from keystore[/opt/mycompany/certs/MyCert.pfx]
    by java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't have the alias for the pfx file. I didn't need to specify one when I used it in Tomcat's server.xml.

It was also suggested that I should use a command like this to import the certificate into a jsk store:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass [password] -destkeystore [JKS keystore file] -deststoretype JKS -destalias [alias] -srckeystore [p12 keystore file] -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass [password] -srcalias [alias]
```

I had to remove the -srcalias portion since I didn't have that, which required me to remove the -destalias as well. So in this case, I don't have a known alias to reference in mycompany.jks

Either way I don't have an alias. I tried importing the pfx file using keytool -import, but that throws a " Input not an X.509 certificate".

What do you guys suggest I should try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your application doesn't use a default `alias` when none is specified. It's quite common for applications/libraries (including Apache Tomcat) to pick the first alias they find when none is specified. However, yours seems to need one.

You can find it using `keytool -list -storetype PKCS12 -keystore` (if needed, use `-v` too to see the alias more clearly). The alias name should be the first part of the line that says something like `2, Jan 12, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry` (here "`2`"), just before the fingerprint.

`keystore -import` is indeed just for certificates.

`keytool -importkeystore` could be used for converting the PKCS#12 store into a JKS store, but you shouldn't need it, since you're able to specify the `PKCS12` type.

Comment: Yes! That resolved the issue. The alias was some very long alpha numeric string.