# Child Error due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a 20 node Hadoop cluster where each node has 8GB memory and an 8-core processor. I sometimes get the following error on a random basis when I have a long running job with 300-600 reducers:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/var/tmp/jim/hadoop-jim/mapred/local/taskTracker/jim/jobcache/job_201305231647_0005/jobToken
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:165)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:92)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: failure to login
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:501)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:463)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1519)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1420)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
... 2 more

Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
  at com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:70)
  at com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:132)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

I tried switching JVM's and both open JDK 1.7 and Oracle JVM 1.6 resulted in the same errors occasionally. It doesn't always happen and when it happens, all tasks running in a particular node fail and that node gets blacklisted. However, the same node usually runs just fine when I submit another job. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on my cluster nodes.

I searched for this error on-line and the only post I could find was from the Cloudera mailing archives where someone running a pseudo distributed Hadoop cluster on a Mac. Other than that, I think I am the first person to come across this issue.

I am not new to Hadoop and generally can solve cluster related problems or mis-configuration issues by myself but I would really appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: It sounds like an alias problem. Check out the answer for this question: [Keystore-Alias-Null-Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831332/keystore-alias-null-error)

Comment: I had the same exception but with a different setting: I wasn't reading files from Hadoop but from Cassandra instead. Fixed it with disabled the eventlog: `spark.eventLog.enabled=false`. Not entirely sure what caused the issue for me, but it was probably related to a RHEL based docker image which could not provide the user name (or something like that). With this setting disabled, everything is running fine.